# PHP Magento Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

the PHP Magento store plugin was Updated, then we discovered this Error Log:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /home/thailandhandicra/public_html/downloader/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php on line 651

When trying to access URL: http://thailandhandicrafts.net/downloader/

I will first include the code from lines 630 - 661 including the specific function containing the error, and then below will contain the full Script. 
Any Help is appreciated, thank you.

Lines 630-661

```
  protected function _createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData)
    {
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attributeData['attribute_code']);
        $attribute = $this->_load($attributeKey);
        if ($attribute) {
            $existsFullAttribute = $attribute->hasIsRequired();
            $fullAttributeData   = array_key_exists('is_required', $attributeData);

            if ($existsFullAttribute || (!$existsFullAttribute && !$fullAttributeData)) {
                return $attribute;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($attributeData['attribute_model'])) {
            $model = $attributeData['attribute_model'];
        } else {
            $model = $entityType->getAttributeModel();
        }
        $attribute = Mage::getModel($model)->setData($attributeData);
        $this->_addAttributeReference(
            $attributeData['attribute_id'],
            $attributeData['attribute_code'],
            $entityTypeCode
        );
        $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attributeData['attribute_code']);
        $this->_save($attribute, $attributeKey);

        return $attribute;
    }
```

Whole script for Config.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Eav
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Eav_Model_Config
{
    const ENTITIES_CACHE_ID     = 'EAV_ENTITY_TYPES';
    const ATTRIBUTES_CACHE_ID   = 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES';

    /**
     * Entity types data
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_entityData;

    /**
     * Attributes data
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_attributeData;

    /**
     * Information about preloaded attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_preloadedAttributes              = array();

    /**
     * Information about entity types with initialized attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_initializedAttributes            = array();

    /**
     * Attribute codes cache array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_attributeCodes                   = array();

    /**
     * Initialized objects
     *
     * array ($objectId => $object)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_objects;

    /**
     * References between codes and identifiers
     *
     * array (
     *      'attributes'=> array ($attributeId => $attributeCode),
     *      'entities'  => array ($entityId => $entityCode)
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_references;

    /**
     * Cache flag
     *
     * @var unknown_type
     */
    protected $_isCacheEnabled                    = null;

    /**
     * Array of attributes objects used in collections
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_collectionAttributes              = array();

    /**
     * Reset object state
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    public function clear()
    {
        $this->_entityData            = null;
        $this->_attributeData         = null;
        $this->_objects               = null;
        $this->_references            = null;
        $this->_preloadedAttributes   = array();
        $this->_initializedAttributes = array();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get object by identifier
     *
     * @param   mixed $id
     * @return  mixed
     */
    protected function _load($id)
    {
        return isset($this->_objects[$id]) ? $this->_objects[$id] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Associate object with identifier
     *
     * @param   mixed $obj
     * @param   mixed $id
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _save($obj, $id)
    {
        $this->_objects[$id] = $obj;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Specify reference for entity type id
     *
     * @param   int $id
     * @param   string $code
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _addEntityTypeReference($id, $code)
    {
        $this->_references['entity'][$id] = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entity type code by id
     *
     * @param   int $id
     * @return  string
     */
    protected function _getEntityTypeReference($id)
    {
        return isset($this->_references['entity'][$id]) ? $this->_references['entity'][$id] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Specify reference between entity attribute id and attribute code
     *
     * @param   int $id
     * @param   string $code
     * @param   string $entityTypeCode
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _addAttributeReference($id, $code, $entityTypeCode)
    {
        $this->_references['attribute'][$entityTypeCode][$id] = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute code by attribute id
     *
     * @param   int $id
     * @param   string $entityTypeCode
     * @return  string
     */
    protected function _getAttributeReference($id, $entityTypeCode)
    {
        if (isset($this->_references['attribute'][$entityTypeCode][$id])) {
            return $this->_references['attribute'][$entityTypeCode][$id];
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get internal cache key for entity type code
     *
     * @param   string $code
     * @return  string
     */
    protected function _getEntityKey($code)
    {
        return 'ENTITY/' . $code;
    }

    /**
     * Get internal cache key for attribute object cache
     *
     * @param   string $entityTypeCode
     * @param   string $attributeCode
     * @return  string
     */
    protected function _getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode)
    {
        return 'ATTRIBUTE/' . $entityTypeCode . '/' . $attributeCode;
    }

    /**
     * Check EAV cache availability
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isCacheEnabled()
    {
        if ($this->_isCacheEnabled === null) {
            $this->_isCacheEnabled = Mage::app()->useCache('eav');
        }
        return $this->_isCacheEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize all entity types data
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _initEntityTypes()
    {
        if (is_array($this->_entityData)) {
            return $this;
        }
        Varien_Profiler::start('EAV: '.__METHOD__);

        /**
         * try load information about entity types from cache
         */
        if ($this->_isCacheEnabled()
            && ($cache = Mage::app()->loadCache(self::ENTITIES_CACHE_ID))) {

            $this->_entityData = unserialize($cache);
            foreach ($this->_entityData as $typeCode => $data) {
                $typeId = $data['entity_type_id'];
                $this->_addEntityTypeReference($typeId, $typeCode);
            }
            Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
            return $this;
        }

        $entityTypesData = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->getCollection()->getData();
        $types           = array();

        /**
         * prepare entity type data
         */
        foreach ($entityTypesData as $typeData) {
            if (!isset($typeData['attribute_model'])) {
                $typeData['attribute_model'] = 'eav/entity_attribute';
            }

            $typeCode   = $typeData['entity_type_code'];
            $typeId     = $typeData['entity_type_id'];

            $this->_addEntityTypeReference($typeId, $typeCode);
            $types[$typeCode] = $typeData;
        }

        $this->_entityData = $types;

        if ($this->_isCacheEnabled()) {
            Mage::app()->saveCache(serialize($this->_entityData), self::ENTITIES_CACHE_ID,
                array('eav', Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::CACHE_TAG)
            );
        }
        Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get entity type object by entity type code/identifier
     *
     * @param   mixed $code
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type
     */
    public function getEntityType($code)
    {
        if ($code instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type) {
            return $code;
        }
        Varien_Profiler::start('EAV: '.__METHOD__);

        if (is_numeric($code)) {
            $entityCode = $this->_getEntityTypeReference($code);
            if ($entityCode !== null) {
                $code = $entityCode;
            }
        }

        $entityKey = $this->_getEntityKey($code);
        $entityType = $this->_load($entityKey);
        if ($entityType) {
            Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
            return $entityType;
        }


        $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type');
        if (isset($this->_entityData[$code])) {
            $entityType->setData($this->_entityData[$code]);
        } else {
            if (is_numeric($code)) {
                $entityType->load($code);
            } else {
                $entityType->loadByCode($code);
            }

            if (!$entityType->getId()) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('eav')->__('Invalid entity_type specified: %s', $code));
            }
        }
        $this->_addEntityTypeReference($entityType->getId(), $entityType->getEntityTypeCode());
        $this->_save($entityType, $entityKey);

        Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
        return $entityType;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize all attributes for entity type
     *
     * @param   string $entityType
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _initAttributes($entityType)
    {
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        if (isset($this->_initializedAttributes[$entityTypeCode])) {
            return $this;
        }
        Varien_Profiler::start('EAV: '.__METHOD__);

        $attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel($entityType->getEntityAttributeCollection())
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType)
            ->getData();

        $codes = array();
        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attribute) {
            $this->_createAttribute($entityType, $attribute);
            $codes[] = $attribute['attribute_code'];
        }

        $entityType->setAttributeCodes($codes);
        $this->_initializedAttributes[$entityTypeCode] = true;

        Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute by code for entity type
     *
     * @param   mixed $entityType
     * @param   mixed $code
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract|false
     */
    public function getAttribute($entityType, $code)
    {
        if ($code instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Interface) {
            return $code;
        }

        Varien_Profiler::start('EAV: '.__METHOD__);

        $entityTypeCode = $this->getEntityType($entityType)->getEntityTypeCode();
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);

        /**
         * Validate attribute code
         */
        if (is_numeric($code)) {
            $attributeCode = $this->_getAttributeReference($code, $entityTypeCode);
            if ($attributeCode) {
                $code = $attributeCode;
            }
        }
        $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $code);

        /**
         * Try use loaded attribute
         */
        $attribute = $this->_load($attributeKey);
        if ($attribute) {
            Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);
            return $attribute;
        }

        if (isset($this->_attributeData[$entityTypeCode][$code])) {
            $data = $this->_attributeData[$entityTypeCode][$code];
            unset($this->_attributeData[$entityTypeCode][$code]);
            $attribute = Mage::getModel($data['attribute_model'], $data);
        } else {
            if (is_numeric($code)) {
                $attribute = Mage::getModel($entityType->getAttributeModel())->load($code);
                if ($attribute->getEntityTypeId() != $entityType->getId()) {
                    return false;
                }
                $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attribute->getAttributeCode());
            } else {
                $attribute = Mage::getModel($entityType->getAttributeModel())
                    ->loadByCode($entityType, $code)
                    ->setAttributeCode($code);
            }
        }

        if ($attribute) {
            $entity = $entityType->getEntity();
            if ($entity && in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $entity->getDefaultAttributes())) {
                $attribute->setBackendType(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract::TYPE_STATIC)
                    ->setIsGlobal(1);
            }
            $attribute->setEntityType($entityType)
                ->setEntityTypeId($entityType->getId());
            $this->_addAttributeReference($attribute->getId(), $attribute->getAttributeCode(), $entityTypeCode);
            $this->_save($attribute, $attributeKey);
        }
        Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__);

        return $attribute;
    }

    /**
     * Get codes of all entity type attributes
     *
     * @param  mixed $entityType
     * @param  Varien_Object $object
     * @return array
     */
    public function getEntityAttributeCodes($entityType, $object = null)
    {
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $attributeSetId = 0;
        if (($object instanceof Varien_Object) && $object->getAttributeSetId()) {
             $attributeSetId = $object->getAttributeSetId();
        }
        $storeId = 0;
        if (($object instanceof Varien_Object) && $object->getStoreId()) {
            $storeId = $object->getStoreId();
        }
        $cacheKey = sprintf('%d-%d', $entityType->getId(), $attributeSetId);
        if (isset($this->_attributeCodes[$cacheKey])) {
            return $this->_attributeCodes[$cacheKey];
        }

        if ($attributeSetId) {
            $attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel($entityType->getEntityAttributeCollection())
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType)
                ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
                ->addStoreLabel($storeId)
                ->getData();
            $attributes = array();
            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeData) {
                $attributes[] = $attributeData['attribute_code'];
                $this->_createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_initAttributes($entityType);
            $attributes = $this->getEntityType($entityType)->getAttributeCodes();
        }

        $this->_attributeCodes[$cacheKey] = $attributes;

        return $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * Preload entity type attributes for performance optimization
     *
     * @param   mixed $entityType
     * @param   mixed $attributes
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    public function preloadAttributes($entityType, $attributes)
    {
        if (is_string($attributes)) {
            $attributes = array($attributes);
        }

        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        if (!isset($this->_preloadedAttributes[$entityTypeCode])) {
            $this->_preloadedAttributes[$entityTypeCode] = $attributes;
        } else {
            $attributes = array_diff($attributes, $this->_preloadedAttributes[$entityTypeCode]);
            $this->_preloadedAttributes[$entityTypeCode] = array_merge($this->_preloadedAttributes[$entityTypeCode],
                $attributes
            );
        }

        if (empty($attributes)) {
            return $this;
        }
        Varien_Profiler::start('EAV: '.__METHOD__ . ':'.$entityTypeCode);

        $attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel($entityType->getEntityAttributeCollection())
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType)
            ->setCodeFilter($attributes)
            ->getData();

        if (!$attributesInfo) {
            Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__ . ':'.$entityTypeCode);
            return $this;
        }

        $attributesData = $codes = array();

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attribute) {
            if (empty($attribute['attribute_model'])) {
                $attribute['attribute_model'] = $entityType->getAttributeModel();
            }

            $attributeCode  = $attribute['attribute_code'];
            $attributeId    = $attribute['attribute_id'];

            $this->_addAttributeReference($attributeId, $attributeCode, $entityTypeCode);
            $attributesData[$attributeCode] = $attribute;
            $codes[]                        = $attributeCode;
        }

        $this->_attributeData[$entityTypeCode] = $attributesData;

        Varien_Profiler::stop('EAV: '.__METHOD__ . ':'.$entityTypeCode);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute object for colection usage
     *
     * @param   mixed $entityType
     * @param   string $attribute
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract|null
     */
    public function getCollectionAttribute($entityType, $attribute)
    {
        $entityType = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        if (is_numeric($attribute)) {
            $attribute = $this->_getAttributeReference($attribute, $entityTypeCode);
            if (!$attribute) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        $attributeKey    = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attribute);
        $attributeObject = $this->_load($attributeKey);
        if ($attributeObject) {
            return $attributeObject;
        }

        return $this->getAttribute($entityType, $attribute);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare attributes for usage in EAV collection
     *
     * @param   mixed $entityType
     * @param   array $attributes
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    public function loadCollectionAttributes($entityType, $attributes)
    {
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        if (!isset($this->_collectionAttributes[$entityTypeCode])) {
            $this->_collectionAttributes[$entityTypeCode] = array();
        }
        $loadedAttributes = array_keys($this->_collectionAttributes[$entityTypeCode]);
        $attributes = array_diff($attributes, $loadedAttributes);

        foreach ($attributes as $k => $attribute) {
            if (is_numeric($attribute)) {
                $attribute = $this->_getAttributeReference($attribute, $entityTypeCode);
            }
            $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attribute);
            if ($this->_load($attributeKey)) {
                unset($attributes[$k]);
            }
        }

        if (empty($attributes)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $attributeCollection = $entityType->getEntityAttributeCollection();
        $attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel($attributeCollection)
            ->useLoadDataFields()
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType)
            ->setCodeFilter($attributes)
            ->getData();

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeData) {
            $attribute = $this->_createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData);
            $this->_collectionAttributes[$entityTypeCode][$attribute->getAttributeCode()] =$attribute;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Create attribute from attribute data array
     *
     * @param string $entityType
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract
     */
    protected function _createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData)
    {
        $entityType     = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        $entityTypeCode = $entityType->getEntityTypeCode();

        $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attributeData['attribute_code']);
        $attribute = $this->_load($attributeKey);
        if ($attribute) {
            $existsFullAttribute = $attribute->hasIsRequired();
            $fullAttributeData   = array_key_exists('is_required', $attributeData);

            if ($existsFullAttribute || (!$existsFullAttribute && !$fullAttributeData)) {
                return $attribute;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($attributeData['attribute_model'])) {
            $model = $attributeData['attribute_model'];
        } else {
            $model = $entityType->getAttributeModel();
        }
        $attribute = Mage::getModel($model)->setData($attributeData);
        $this->_addAttributeReference(
            $attributeData['attribute_id'],
            $attributeData['attribute_code'],
            $entityTypeCode
        );
        $attributeKey = $this->_getAttributeKey($entityTypeCode, $attributeData['attribute_code']);
        $this->_save($attribute, $attributeKey);

        return $attribute;
    }

    /**
     * Validate attribute data from import
     *
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _validateAttributeData($attributeData = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($attributeData)) {
            return false;
        }
        $requiredKeys = array(
            'attribute_id',
            'attribute_code',
            'entity_type_id',
            'attribute_model'
        );
        foreach ($requiredKeys as $key) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $attributeData)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Import attributes data from external source
     *
     * @param string|Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type $entityType
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     */
    public function importAttributesData($entityType, array $attributes)
    {
        $entityType = $this->getEntityType($entityType);
        foreach ($attributes as $attributeData) {
            if (!$this->_validateAttributeData($attributeData)) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->_createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, it is impossible for us to tell where it actually break. it looks like $model returns null but why, you have to go up into every function that gets called to see what's failing. I believe there is a very small chance that you can fix it. Better contact the module developers.

Comment: There is no Module developer :/ Someone please help

Comment: In the stack trace, it's what creates the `Call to a member function setData()` that is the breakage, not the cascade of messages afterwards. Find out what's feeding a bogus or null value into `$attributeData` when  `protected function _createAttribute($entityType, $attributeData)` is called.

Comment: can you print a stacktrace and add it to you question ?

Comment: The Problem started when this extension was installed, and then the extension was removed, but the errors remained: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wholesale-retail-module.html 

Any thoughts?